# fileupload control not working while i publish it

Tags: c#

I got a problem that when i publish my Code to server the file upload control not working  instead of giving me error message as

> Access to the path'D:\WWWROOT\OCPL_PUBLISH\Application\New_Land_Management\Old_Khatian\ROR_01_0_1.pdf' is denied.                                       Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>
> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'D:\WWWROOT\OCPL_PUBLISH\Application\New_Land_Management\Old_Khatian\ROR_01_0_1.pdf' is   denied.
>
> ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity. ASP.NET has a base   process identity (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and the configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if   the application is not impersonating. If the application is impersonating via , the identity will be the anonymous user (typically   IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated request user.
>
> To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in File Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add" to add the appropriate user or   group. Highlight the ASP.NET account, and check the boxes for the desired access.
>
> Source Error: 
>   An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be    identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'D:\WWWROOT\OCPL_PUBLISH\Application\New_Land_Management\Old_Khatian\ROR_01_0_1.pdf' is denied.]
>          ocpl_rollout.Application.New_Land_Management.New_land_Insert.btnUpdatekhata_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +2274
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +11758848
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +150
>          System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5028

I try and search a lot about this error but failed i request you to suggest me some resolution of this problem. i use this codes and the file path given like this

```
   protected void UploadKhataDoc(FileUpload doc, string file)
    {
        if (doc.HasFile)
        {
            doc.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Application/New_Land_ManagementOld_Khatian/" + file.ToString()));
        }
    }
```

Comment: The issue is with your host. Contact them for support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]you have to change access permission of folder on your sever

Show red rectangular portion in the attached image

Comment: well sir i tried but failed so can you help me how can i do this please

Comment: okie sir i am trying and let you know if i got sucess or not .

Thank you for the quick help.

Comment: login to your  plex and open httpdoc folder here you get your folder in which you want to save your uploaded file ->  open menu of desire folder here you get option to change permission